# Can i root my Sm-G970u1? (snapdragon)

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I recently bought a unlocked S10e g970u1 thinking I would be able to root. All info I have seen says this can't be done if has snapdragon, which mine is. I have AT&T now but as I understand it the carrier is not the issue in this case so changing the Sim card wouldn't make a difference. I'm no expert here and appreciate the help.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3980463

Comment: Note that by rooting as far as I know you will permanently disable the Knox security feature for this device and hence all apps that rely on Knox will no longer work.